# Complicated query with GROUP BY and range of prices in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, ruby-on-rails-3

In my DB table, I have a lot of products (several of which the same product). If the product in table is e.g. 5 times, so first could be its price $10, then $20, $30, $40 and $50.

I am trying to make a statement, where will be every product printed just once, and if the product will be stored in table e.g. 5 times as above, so I would like to print about this product also prices range.  Example:

```
Mobile phone: $300
Bicycle: $1000
T-Shirt blue: $10 - $30
```

Exist any elegant way to do?
I am trying to do following way:

```
Product.find(:all, 
             :per_page => 20, :page => page,
             :group => "name",
             :order => name)
```

But as I wrote above, I am thinking about an option, how to get the range of prices... Is it possible to do in one query?

Comment: This is tagged as Rails 3, but your active_record syntax looks like Rails 2. Assuming you're using will_paginate, I would expect: `Product.order('name').group('name').paginate(:page => page, :per_page => 20)`. This is likely **not** related to your problem however.

Answer (score 1):

```
select
    name,
    if(min_price = max_price, concat('$', min_price), concat('$', min_price, ' - $', max_price) as price
from (select
      name,
      min(price) as min_price,
      max(price) as max_price
      from product
      group by 1) x
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply, `Bohemian`. But, tell the truth, I don't know how this complicated query rewrite to RoR notation

Answer (score 1):

Sure.  The query should probably look something along these lines:

```
SELECT category, (SELECT MAX(price)
                  FROM products as b
                  WHERE a.category = b.category),
                 (SELECT MIN(price)
                  FROM products as b
                  WHERE b.category = a.category)
FROM products 
GROUP BY category
```

I would reccommend the formatting be constructed by your display code, though, not handled in your query.

---

Thinking about it, here's an alternate version:

```
WITH priceRange (category, min, max) as (SELECT category, MIN(price), max(price)
                                         FROM products
                                         GROUP BY category)
SELECT productDetails, min, max
FROM products as a
JOIN priceRange as b
ON b.category = a.category
```

Might even perform better.

---

Okay, this is without actually using RoR, only looking at the documentation....
One problem you may be having is the fact that you're trying to grant a field to an object, that isn't in the database.  You're probably going to need to specifically select these fields into a new object, or perform the grouping work outside of the database.  That said...
There appears to be a `find_by_sql` method, allowing you to input an sql query of your choice.  I'm not sure if the CTE one would work, but I suspect it might.

Comment: Thank you `X-Zero`, these queries are a bit more demanding, so now I am struggling, how to write in Rails